# Is it possible in python to pack a set of integers in non-byte increments?

Tags: python, binary

Let's say I have three unsigned integers, `A`, `B`, and `C`, and I know the maximum values of each. Both `A` and `B` are less than 2<sup>14</sup>, and `C` is less than 2<sup>4</sup>. Since `14 + 14 + 4 = 32`, I should be able to store these three integers in 32 bits, right?

If so, how can I do this in python? Struct.pack only appears to support byte-sized registers, so I would be limited to 'HHB', which is 40 bits (8 more than I need). Can this be done, or am I missing some fundamental concepts here?

Comment: Relevant, though I don't know whether the answers are still up to date: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663/what-is-the-best-way-to-do-bit-field-manipulation-in-python

Comment: Could you do it yourself using bitwise operators?

Comment: @figs I suppose I could, I just don't work with bitwise often enough to know the solution.  I did just find a library called bitstring that seems to do what I want.

Answer (score 0):

The library sounds like the way to go, but just for fun with bitwise operations:

```
a_in, b_in, c_in = 15220, 9021, 9
a_bits, b_bits, c_bits = 14, 14, 4

packed = a_in << b_bits + c_bits | b_in << c_bits | c_in

a_out = (packed & 2 ** a_bits - 1 << b_bits + c_bits) >> b_bits + c_bits
b_out = (packed & 2 ** b_bits - 1 << c_bits) >> c_bits
c_out =  packed & 2 ** c_bits - 1

print packed    # 3989976025 = 11101101110100100011001111011001
print a_out     # 15220      = 11101101110100
print b_out     # 9021       =               10001100111101
print c_out     # 9          =                             1001
```

Answer (score 0):

Pack it yourself with bit operators:

```
(A<<18)|(B<<4)|C
```

Then use `struct.pack` on the 32-bit result.